# If $\phi$ is a tautology then dual $\phi$ is a contradiction.

Tags: logic, induction, boolean-algebra, algebraic-logic

If $\phi$ is a statement form, Prove that:
$\vDash \phi$  iff $\phi^{d}$ is a contradiction.

where $\phi^{d}$ is the dual of $\phi .$

$\phi^{d}$ is the dual of $\phi $ is defined by:

(i) $A^{d} = A$ for any statement letter A.

(ii)$(\lnot \phi)^{d} = \lnot (\phi^{d})$

(iii)$(\phi \land \psi )^{d} = \phi^{d}\lor \psi^{d}.$ and sililarly for $\vee$

(iv)$(\phi \Rightarrow \psi )^{d} = \lnot (\psi^{d}\Rightarrow \phi^{d}) $

Also, we have taken a theorem that states that:
$$(\psi^{d})^{d} = \psi$$

I think it may be solved by induction,Could anyone give me an advice?

Comment: Definition of *dual* ?

Comment: In any case : yes, must be proved by induction.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  I have reedited the question including the definition of duality.

Comment: Good; probably the best approach is to prove by induction that, for every formula $\varphi$ and every truth-valuation $v$ : $v(\varphi^d)=v(\lnot \varphi)$.

Comment: With the dual defined as you have, the result you state simply isn't true (at least not in classical logic). Indeed take $\phi = A \lor \neg A$ for any "statement letter" $A$. Then $\phi^d = A^d \lor (\neg A)^d = A\lor \neg A$, and $\models \phi$, and $\models \phi^d$. So you should probably change the definition or the result

Comment: Maybe with (iii) $(\phi \wedge \psi)^d = \phi^d \vee \psi^d$ (similarly with $\vee$ changed to $\wedge$) and (iv) $(\phi \Rightarrow \psi)^d = \psi^d \Rightarrow \phi^d$

Comment: I am sorry I will correct it thanks to all of u

Comment: The operator  $\Rightarrow$ is redundant if you have already $\lor, \land, \lnot$.

Comment: @amrsa  I do not think the dual of implication that you wrote is true

Comment: @miracle173  No I am sure what I wrote is the definition that we have..... but I will check something and answer you.

Comment: my last comment was nonsense. I will delete it.

Comment: As you like @miracle173

Comment: You are absolutely right. The correct version is, of course, the one you have now (also in the answer from Bram28). It is actually easy to derive, using the trick pointed out by miracle173. I'm sorry if I made you lose some time with this. And thank you for warning me!

Comment: you are welcome    we are learning from each other it is not a big deal @amrsa  all of us sometimes made mistakes we are human beings.

Comment: @miracle173  no my definition said that the rule of duality for a statement letter is exactly as stated in the question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  your idea is not clear for me..... could u please clarify it?

Comment: our professor said that the proof of the statement for the case of a statement letter is as follows or using $\phi$ is not a tautology is equivalent to $\phi^{d}$ is not a contradiction. could u clarify for me @Bram28?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of the dual is not correct.

In general, for any two-place logical operator $\times$, the *dual expression* of $\phi \times \psi$ is $\phi^d \times^d \psi^d$, where $\times^d$ is the *dual operator* of $\times$, which you can find by: $\phi \times^d \psi \Leftrightarrow \neg (\neg \phi \times \neg \psi)$.

Thus, we find that:

$(\phi \land \psi )^d = \phi^d \lor \psi^d$

$(\phi \lor \psi )^d = \phi^d \land \psi^d$

$(\phi \rightarrow \psi)^d = \phi^d \not \leftarrow \psi^d$ (= $\neg (\psi^d \rightarrow \phi^d)$)

Etc.

That last one is a little unusual, and makes you wonder if you need to consider and figure out the dual operator for all 16 two-place logical operators. Fortunately, you don't have to: the good news is that in order to prove the desired result, all you need to do is use induction and use the *general* definition of dual expressions and dual operators as defined above (plus consideration of atomic statements and negations of course).

Now, it turns out that this is still not easy ...

**HINT**

As you will have noticed  $\phi^d \not \Leftrightarrow \neg \phi$! So that's not the way to prove it.

However: Define the *complement* statement $\phi'$ of a statement $\phi$ to be that statement that puts a negation in front of every atomic statement in $\phi$. Recursively:

$A' = \neg A$ for any atomic $A$

$(\neg \phi)' = \neg (\phi)'$

$(\phi \times \psi)' = \phi' \times \psi'$

Now you should be able to prove (by induction of course) that $\phi^d\Leftrightarrow \neg \phi'$.  And from that, the desired result follows fairly quickly.

Comment: you are right I have made a mistake I will correct it sorry  @Bram28

Comment: yes I need a hint.

Comment: @MathLover OK, I'll add it to the Answer

Comment: I do not think that your dual of implication is right ..... please check it

Comment: @MathLover OK ... $(\phi \rightarrow \psi)^d = (\phi^d \rightarrow^d \psi) \Leftrightarrow \neg (\neg \phi^d \rightarrow \neg \psi^d) \Leftrightarrow \neg (\psi^d \rightarrow \phi^d)$. So that looks correct. ...  Oh! I forgot to add the $d$'s! OK, my mistake! ... corrected now. Thanks!

Comment: I am not so sure of your definition for $x^{d}.$  Could u give me your reference if u do not mind?

Comment: @MathLover It's from my notes ... but I believe I got this from 'Intermediate Logic' by David Bostock

Comment: what do you mean by "all 16 two-place logical operators"

Comment: what is the book that you took from before "David Bostock"?

Comment: @Mathlover $\land$, $\lor$, $\rightarrow$, and $\leftrightarrow$ are all two-place (binary) logical operators: they take in 2 truth-values.  But there are 12 more.  Think of all the possible truth-tables you can make for a two-place operator ... there should be 16 of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55199/discussion-between-bram28-and-mathlover).

Comment: Though this answer finally contains the right arguments it is rather confusing and I think you have to make a proof for $\lnot$, $\lor$ and $\land$ to show that $t^d=\lnot(t')$.

Comment: @miracle173 yes, I did not include a proof for that part ... I intentionally left that to the OP. That's why I put **HINT** in big fat letters above that part. I don't understand why you would downvote for that :(