# Use induction to prove the generalized Distributive laws.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra, algebraic-logic

Prove that:
$$\phi \vee (\psi_{1} \wedge ...\wedge \psi_{n}) = (\phi \vee \psi_{1})\wedge ... \wedge (\phi \vee \psi_{n}).$$

I think the induction may be the ordinary induction and not course of values induction, right?

thanks.

Comment: The double induction is when you have $(\phi_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \phi_m) \vee (\psi_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \psi_n)$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi  So it is not an example of a double induction? So may be I understand wrong.

Comment: Write $\phi \vee (\psi_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \psi_n)$ as $\phi \vee ((\psi_1 \wedge \cdots \psi_{n-1}) \wedge \psi_n))$ and apply distributivity to get $(\phi \vee (\psi_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \psi_{n-1})) \wedge (\phi \vee \psi_n)$.  Then invoke the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Could you please see if my definition of duality for a statement letter is not reasonable (as we defined it in the lecture by this) here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180324/if-phi-is-a-tautology-then-dual-phi-is-a-contradiction/2180543?noredirect=1#comment4486185_2180543

Comment: Your definition of dual of a statement letter is correct.

Comment: Thank u very much @FabioSomenzi